# Akavache Exception calling BlobCache.LocalMachine

Tags: xamarin.forms, akavache

I've a new VS2017 Xamarin Forms project with the following:

- akavache 5.0.0
- akavache.core 5.0.0
- akavache.sqlite3 5.0.0
- Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247

I've added Akavache to both my iOS and PCL projects and the ApplicationName is being set to the Bundle Identifier.  When I call BlobCache.LocalMachine (PCL project), I receive the following exception:

System.Exception: You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().  If you are using a bundle package, this is done by calling SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init(). occurred

I've added to SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init to the FinishedLaunching method in my AppDelegate (iOS project), however I still receive the same error.  I've also tried SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init() but that didn't work.

Is there some additional setup that's required for Akavache to work?

Comment: Try adding this line `SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3());` in your iOS project

Comment: I get a compiler error on SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3?

Comment: Is there any other SQLite provider? Maybe you can figure out through IntelliSense?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I parked this for a while and have just reinstalled Akavache.  This time I installed in the iOS project before the PCL - which shouldn't have made any difference, however it worked this time!!

Comment: That is great! The order shouldn't matter indeed, but I'm glad it worked out